# How to call QProcess with schtask

Tags: winapi, qt

I'd like to know what's the correct command for my the code . 
My code isn't working and can't create a Task.

```
QString TaskName= "Task Name";
QString Create = "/create /tn";
QString Path  = " /tr c:\Control.exe";
QString  sch =  "/sc daily /st 1:57:00 /ed 08/02/2011";

QString Program ="schtasks";

int i = QProcess::execute(Program,QStringList() <<Create<<TaskName<<Path<<sch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it , You need to put the time as 00:00:00 .
Thanks